Finding k for a Quadratic Equation with Roots in Specific Ranges
I am working on the quadratic equation:
${(k-5)x^2} -2kx+k-4=0$
I need to find all values of $k$ such that one root of the equation is smaller than $1$, and the other root is greater than $2$.
Here's what I've tried so far:

I know that for a quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$, the roots are given by:

$$x_1,x_2=\frac{-b±\sqrt{ b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

I also know the properties of the roots:

$ \bullet$ Sum of the roots: $Sum= \frac{-b}{a} $
$ \bullet$ Product of the roots: $Product= \frac{c}{a} $
But I'm stuck on how to apply the condition $ x_1 \lt {1}$ and $x_2\lt{2} $ (or vice versa).
Could someone guide me through the process of solving this?
Thank you in advance!

So, what do you get when you put the actual coefficients into the quadratic formula?

After reporting coefficients in your $a,b,c$ show the square root is $\ge 0 \implies k>0$ so you can determine the bigger root is the one with the $+$ sign and the lower root the one with the $-$ sign. Now compare the roots with $1$ and $2$. Start with the lower root, it is easier. For the greater one you have another quadratic to solve, but the first condition on the lower root helps to decide.

You have to consider $2$ possible cases.
One is that for the quadratic equation $$(k-5)x^{2}-2kx+(k-4)=0$$ $a>0$
And the other one is $a<0$.
Where, $a=(k-5)$
$1^{st}$ case :
If $(k-5)<0$ ; then
$f(1)>0$ and also $f(2)>0$.
Now, $f(1)=-9$ and $f(2)=k-24$
Now, note that this condition is not correct, because if $(k-5)<0$, then $f(1)$ and $f(2)$ both have to be greater than $0$ at a same time which is not the scenario.
Now let's come to the $2^{nd}$ condition.
If $(k-5)>0$, then
$f(1)<0$ and $f(2)<0$.
That is $f(1)<0$ and $f(2)<0$
Now, $f(1)<0$ is correct because $f(1)=-9$
And also $f(2)<0$ which implies $(k-24)<0$
Now, the following conditions are :
$(k-5)>0....(1)$
$(k-24)<0....(2)$
Which implies $k\in(5,24)$

I guess you need to translate your conditions into something more useful:
$x_1<1$ and $x_2>2$ (the average of $1$ and $2$ is $\frac{3}{2}$), this can be translated as:
$x_1 - \frac{3}{2} < -\frac{1}{2}$
$x_2 - \frac{3}{2} > +\frac{1}{2}$
This can be rewritten as: $|x_{i|i \in \{1,2\}}| > \frac{1}{2}$
This can lead to an equation in $k$.
Have fun :-)
